# Deleted Assets still show up in the build log?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So with the help of the "Editor Log" after building I´m trying to reduce the file size of the app I´m creating. But for some reason the Assets I´m deleting are still included in the build. 
The Log:
(All in Assets/Textures/Sprites/Sticker/)

...
16.0 mb  3.0% Sticker_1.png
15.9 mb  3.0% Sticker_2.png
15.8 mb  3.0% QR/Sticker_3.png
13.8 mb  2.6% Sticker_4.png
11.8 mb  2.2% Sticker_5.png
11.8 mb  2.2% QR/Sticker_6.png
11.6 mb  2.2% Sticker_7.png
...

The thing is, that I already deleted the whole "QR" folder. But for some reason, it still shows up in the log and the app size didn´t go down. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the file size of the app try looking at:

[Remove unused assets](https://answers.unity.com/questions/683644/remove-unused-assets.html)

and at

[Find Unused Assets In Project](https://answers.unity.com/questions/57909/find-unused-assets-in-project.html)

For you second problem (*'Assets I´m deleting are still included in the build'*):

Try exiting your project and looking at the files from the file explorer, if they are not there they won't be in th e build (probably just still in the unity settings).

Comment: Yeah I just found out that a restart fixed the issue. Still weird that they were still included in the build and app size didn´t change until the restart.

Thanks for the ressources though, gonna look into it now!

Comment: This is probably because when you restart it you save and reload everything and all the settings update.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
"File>Build settings..." (or just Ctrl+Shift+B) window select a drop down "Clean Build" from from "Build" button [clean build option image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZSIM.png).
it resolved my same issue
Ref: [https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html[2]](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html%5B2%5D)